# After Upgrading Ubuntu to latest version, display is corrupted in many applications

Tags: graphics, google-chrome, vmware, display-manager

Recently I upgraded the Ubuntu to latest version here is the detail:
[image]

But after upgrading to this version, Chrome and some other apps are behaving strangely. for instance look at the various screenshots of chrome where CSS colours are "spilled":

[image]

here is another one
[image]

this is how github looks:
[image]

[image]

also Rider (C# IDE) and Intellij Idea Icons appear are white squares.

Anyone facing the same issues? what is the solution in this case or any workaround?
Firefox is unaffected and so is VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

You will wish to disable `Hardware Acceleration` under Google Chrome's settings, as shown in the screenshot here:

[image]

Apologies for being unable to crop the excess regions, as I've only just reinstalled Ubuntu Linux myself and was experiencing the same issue as you are. The solution I have outlined is what fixed the problem for me.

Comment: but it happens in some other apps too. I turned off that option. problem reduced but not completely gone